# Angularjs syntax error

Tags: angularjs, json

Trying to output data from an API:

```
{{forecast.list.rain.3h}}
```

Gives an error: 
Syntax Error: Token '.3' is an unexpected token at column 19 of the expression [forecast.list.rain.3h] starting at [.3h].
saying that .3 is the error, integers not allowed in {{....}}?
This seems problematic when the data is stored like this:

```
rain:Object
3h:0.005
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can't reference this property with dot-notation since a valid identifier may not start with a number. Use `{{forecast.list.rain['3h']}}` instead.